# How to navigate to a "Not Secured" web page using PhantomJS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I was trying to navigate to a web page which is not secured.

When I try to do this using PhantomJS, it's not navigating the web page. I can see that by debugging the code.

So, how should I navigate to the "Not Secured" web page using PhantomJS?

Below is my code.

```
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(@"C:\Driver\phantomjs\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xx.aspx");
```

Comment: What does "not secured" mean?

Comment: When the SSL certificate expired ,We need t manualy add an exception to the web browser. I think web sites not having https

Comment: In your example you're trying to access to http resource. Hence certificates would not be checked there in any way. There might be an issue when server does not allow http connections though.

Comment: If you have certificate validation issues, try to apply the solution suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium. This is for python language however the concept can be migrated to any other language.

Comment: @alaexey R you are awesome. I found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this on .net c# with PhantomJSDriver with selenium web driver 3.1

```
[TestMethod]
public void headless()
{


    var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Driver\phantomjs\");
    driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
    driverService.AddArgument("--web-security=no");
    driverService.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("XXXXXX.aspx");

    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own question as an answer to marked them answered.